# jquery href link onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Trying to call a function when a link is clicked -

```
<a href="" id="extension">Extensions</a>
```

js -

```
$("#extension").click( function () {
    chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://extensions'});
});
```

But when the link is clicked the function is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging or check the console?

Comment: Shouldn't it be
    $("#extension").on('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://entensions'});
    });

Comment: @Dean.DePue check out jquery docs on `on` and `click`; both are applicable, `on` is used more for event delegation

Comment: Need more information ... is the HTML part of a popup? Is it part of page content? Depending on this, is the Javascript code part of popup Javascript or background script or content script??

Comment: yes, I checked the console. I also put a breakpoint, the code is not getting executed. And its not a popup. But the page is opened by clicking on the extension button.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues where I'll have to put return false; in my function as the last line before the curly brace.  This will (as I understand) negate the browser's default functionality and just do what you want in your function.

so your code would look like this:

```
    $("#extension").click( function () {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://extensions'});
        return false;
    });
```

Also might want to check your chrome Dev tools for any JS errors (hit F12 and click on the console tab, then click your link).  Hope this helps!

Comment: I also assume that you have included a reference to the jQuery library :).  Have you tried using 'onclick' instead?  e.g. 
    <script>
        createTab() {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://extensions'});
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    ...
    <a href="" id="extension" onclick="createTab(); return false;">Extensions</a>